# Appending the table inside a PSQL schema

Tags: postgresql

My goal is to append all the tables in the schema. Is there a way to loop through the table in one specific schema, and use those tables to append to each other to create a bigger table? (Here, all my tables have the same format for the columns).

Comment: `psql` is the Postgres command line client  it has no schema. You need to change to Postgres or Postgresql schema. In addition you will need to update your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do. For instance: 1) Do the smaller tables need to remain? 2) Do you already have the new table defined? 3) Are there repeated data in the tables? 4) Do they all have the same constraints? 5) Is table partitioning an option?

Comment: Thanks for responding me and I apologize for my Occam's razor question. So for the response of your question: 1) Yes 2) Yes 3) Could be, but it's totally fine repeating the data 4) Similar constraint and 5) A partition is an option.

Comment: ALTER TABLE small_table INHERIT big_table;
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that!